# Oracle PL/SQL: How to use a column conditionally as it may not exist in older versions of a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a simple anonymous procedure which tries a perform SELECT queries on a table. Problem is in an older version of this table, few columns did not exist and these new columns were introduced in a newer version of table structure.

I am checking if this new column exists and then conditionally using SELECT query if the only columns exists. But seems due to static compilation it reports:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ERRORTYPE": invalid identifier
```

How do I handle this? Below is the sample procedure,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  errorType_column_exists number := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO errorType_column_exists 
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLS 
  WHERE owner = 'DEV' 
  AND table_name = 'Table1'
  AND column_name = 'ERRORTYPE';
  IF (errorType_column_exists = 1) THEN
      FOR r_row IN (SELECT ErrorMsg
                FROM DEV.Table1
                 WHERE (ErrorType != 'Missing' OR ErrorType IS NULL) 
                AND ROWNUM <= 100)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_row.ErrorMsg);
      END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: you can use dynamic sql... simple `execute immediate` would solve the problem

Comment: Some context please. When you say "older version of this table" what exactly is occurring? Do you have multiple databases with schemas of various vintages? Are you trying to write one piece of code which will run on all configurations?

Comment: Hi, Why procedure is common across version ?! you should have different procedure implementation in each version . so that each procedure use correct column for that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code has to be compiled before it can be run. The code inside your loop will only compile in a schema where TABLE1 has a column called `error_type`.

The only way to write an anonymous block which will compile against all versions of the schema is to use dynamic SQL.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;  
DECLARE  
    errorType_column_exists number := 0;
    Lnt sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll;
  BEGIN 
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO errorType_column_exists 
     FROM ALL_TAB_COLS 
     WHERE owner = 'DEV' 
     AND table_name = 'Table1' 
     AND column_name = 'ERRORTYPE'; 
     IF (errorType_column_exists = 1)
     THEN 
            execute Immediate 'SELECT ErrorMsg FROM DEV.Table1 WHERE (ErrorType != ''Missing'' OR ErrorType IS NULL) AND ROWNUM <= 100'
            bulk collect into lnt;
            for idx in 1..lnt.count()
          LOOP  
                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lnt(idx)); 
    END LOOP; 
    END IF; 
 END; 
 /
```

Comment: Sorry the layout is so shonky but formatting blocks of code in the SE app is Teh Suck!

Comment: Thanks this really helped!

Comment: Noticed the line "bulk collect into lnt;" throws - "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" when the select query returns empty. Is there a way to guard this?

Actually I have changed the variable declaration like below:
lnt sys.odcivarchar2list;

Comment: Same with even "Lnt sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll;"
I see below error SQL query return no rows,

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).

Comment: The number list type was an error on my part because I hadn't read your code properly. However, DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL should be okay providing `error_type` is a string not longer than 1000 characters. If it is longer than that you will need to define your own collection type.

Comment: Please understand, I have just edited the code **you provided**. I don't have your schema or data so I can't test the code. All I can do is make suggestions. You will need to debug the code you run in your environment.

Comment: Thanks. ErrorMsg column is VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR).
But seems this isn't the issue for now, when SQL query does not return any rows then I see - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the FOR LOOP condition; this one so 't hurl if your query returns zero rows.

Answer (score 2):

The official Oracle way to do this is to use conditional compilation:

```
alter session set PLSQL_CCFlags = 'schema_version:2'

DECLARE
  errorType_column_exists number := 0;
BEGIN

  FOR r_row IN (SELECT ErrorMsg
            FROM DEV.Table1
           $if $$schema_version >= 2 $then
             WHERE (ErrorType != 'Missing' OR ErrorType IS NULL)
           $else
             WHERE 1=1
           $end
            AND ROWNUM <= 100)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_row.ErrorMsg);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

So you would have to set the PL/SQL compiler flags according to the schema version you are dealing with.

Comment: I did consider suggesting CC as a solution but it's a bit fiddly for anonymous blocks. Also in this case there appears to be no need to do any processing if the column doesn't exist, so I am not sure your implementation is correct. However this approach is a good fit for other slightly different use cases.